# R: Trouble using mutate to produce variable based on list component outputted from bc.mean.sd function

Tags: r, dplyr

As part of a metanalysis I've been trying to compute missing means and sds usingmedian/IQR data using the bc.mean.sd from estmeansd package (v0.2.1). I've cleaned the data down to a simple set (shown below) to explore the issue.

```
library(estmeansd)
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble::tribble(
          ~iqr1       ,    ~median        ,        ~iqr2    ,  ~n,
          21.1        ,      23.35        ,         25.2    ,  40,
          20.8        ,      25.00        ,         27.0    ,  30,
          26.8        ,      28.00        ,         29.0    ,  30,
          15.0        ,      22.50        ,         29.0    ,  30,
          26.8        ,      28.00        ,         29.0    ,  30,
          20.8        ,      25.00        ,         27.0    ,  30,
          23.5        ,      26.00        ,         28.0    ,  20
          )
```

The function returns a list with different components, and I have been wanting to transform my dataset using mutate to produce 2 new variables per row, one with the $est.mean, one the $est.sd.

The function works fine with manual values, and when I assign single values in it seems to work as well eg

```
set.seed(1)
  test <- bc.mean.sd(q1.val = dfm_cm$cognitive_iqr1_treat[1],   
                       med.val = dfm_cm$cognitive_median_treat[1],  
                       q3.val  = dfm_cm$cognitive_iqr2_treat[1],    
                       n  = dfm_cm$n_treat[1])$est.mean
```

I've tried to code this using mutate as:

```
  set.seed(1)
  df2 <-  df %>%
    mutate(
      new_t_mean =  bc.mean.sd(q1.val = iqr1,   
                               med.val = median,  
                               q3.val  = iqr2,    
                                    n  = n)$est.mean
    )
```

This actually works if I only have one row (inserting `slice(1) %>%` after the first pipe operator), but if there are any more rows than that (as per above) I get error messages:

```
Warning messages:
1: Problem while computing `new_t_mean = ...$est.mean`.
i the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

And indeed, all the returned values are the same.

I could brute force this but I want to understand what I am doing wrong, especially as I have used this $ assigment in a very similar way without problem in another part of my code (included below for ref, but NB it uses a different function and different variables to those I have presented - suffice to say it works). I think there may be something going on behind the scenes of the function that is above my current expertise in R.

Any help much appreciated.

```
Working analoguous example
library(esc)
df3 <- df %>%
  mutate(es =  esc_mean_sd(grp1m = mean_cont, 
                           grp1sd = sd_cont, 
                           grp1n = n_cont  ,   
                           grp2m = mean_treat,   
                           grp2sd = sd_treat,  
                           grp2n = n_treat ,   
                           es.type = "g")$es
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `rowwise()` like this:

```
f <- function(v1,m,v2,n) {
 res = bc.mean.sd(q1.val = v1,med.val = m,  q3.val  = v2, n  = n)
 list("est.mean" = res$est.mean, "est.sd" = res$est.sd)
}

df %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(k = list(f(iqr1,median,iqr2,n))) %>%
  unnest_wider(k)
```

Output:

```
   iqr1 median  iqr2     n est.mean est.sd
  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
1  21.1   23.4  25.2    40     22.9   3.20
2  20.8   25    27      30     23.6   4.79
3  26.8   28    29      30     27.8   1.73
4  15     22.5  29      30     21.8   8.09
5  26.8   28    29      30     28.0   1.76
6  20.8   25    27      30     23.6   4.52
7  23.5   26    28      20     25.5   3.88
```

The function is not necessary; you can also do it directly, like this:

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(k = list(bc.mean.sd(
    q1.val=iqr1,
    med.val=median,
    q3.val=iqr2,
    n=n)[c("est.mean", "est.sd")])
    ) %>% 
  unnest_wider(k)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked great! I will get more familiar with rowwise. (The function was helpful as I suddenly figured out that if-statements could let me run this on unfiltered dataset and speed up the workflow.)